# Words similar to 대여섯?

Tags: vocabulary, meaning

I know that 대여섯 means five or six, but I'm wondering why the '대' takes the meaning of 'five' here? Are there other words similar to this that mean 'A and A+1'. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually words like this all the way to at least 8:

- 한두, 한둘: 1 or 2
- 두세, 두셋: 2 or 3
- 서너, 서넛: 3 or 4
- 네댓, 네다섯: 4 or 5
- 대여섯: 5 or 6
- 예닐곱: 6 or 7
- 일여덟: 7 or 8

In each case, the two numbers are compounded, with the first one reduced to just one syllable.  In some cases, a contraction seems to have altered the first syllable - as in 대여섯 and 예닐곱 - but I'm not sure the mechanism that brought about this sound change.

Comment: There are words like 대엿, 일고여덟, 여덟아홉 (= 엳아홉), and 여남은, too. There are also *non-standard variations* such as 다서여섯 and 여서일곱. The standard dictionary provides the etymologies of 대엿 and 예닐곱.

Comment: Ah thanks a lot! I've actually heard 한둘 and 두세 before but they've never sounded strange to me haha. I haven't heard of the higher numbers before? Do people use the irregular forms in conversation or are people more likely to say, for example, 여서일곱 instead of 예닐곱?

Comment: @KrJpnLinguistNoob For 서너, you can hear it from the song, "내 동생": 이름은 하나인데 별명은 **서너** 개. Those who know 대여섯 and 예닐곱 do not use 다서여섯 and 여서일곱, but it is true that a lot of people use 다서여섯 and 여서일곱 in conversation. I have never heard anyone say 대여섯, 일여덟, or 엳아홉. One of the reasons seems to be that people almost never use the unit 자, which is used as 대 자 and 예 자.